# Consequences of having a device that can transform heat back to stored energy in a limited way?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, energy, thermodynamics

My setting uses reactors that work on a fictional gas-like inert substance that can safely store an impossibly high amount of energy in itself (breaking the e=mc^2 equation and causing Einstein to curse at me). It is hinted at as being artificially created by an ancient Precursor species (now not present in the Galaxy) capable of reshaping the laws of physics.

The setting also has a device called a "reclamator", which can act as a heat-sink to absorb the massive amount of heat the reactor should output, using the heat to "recharge" that substance with energy (other than this device, the energy can only be extracted from the substance via a reactor), basically putting almost all the "wasted" energy back in the system to be reused.

This device is a replicable black box, an artifact of the mentioned Precursor species, meaning that it can be copied, but it can't be understood and works only when built "as is", and nobody has the necessary knowledge to comprehend why. It seems to be specifically designed to work with reactors using the fictional substance, utilizing the quirks of necessary constructive elements they must possess regardless of the overall design (So you can't install it on a thermonuclear reactor, or have it soak up ambient heat alone by itself).

The device is rather bulky, so only large reactors, fit for capital ships, can be equipped with it, and it requires a minimum amount of heat energy input to operate. It also processes the heat at a finite capacity, so having too much of it will overheat the device and break it. Thus, the largest ships of the setting still need to divert some part of the heat they generate into radiators. It also still consumes power while doing its thing.

**Considering all the above, are there any unintentional side effects and uses of having such a device in the setting that aren't covered by the limitations described?**

This device was born out of me wanting to justify the general lack of radiators on my spaceship and space station designs, despite the high amount of heat they *must* be producing. I want to know if there are any hindsight-obvious unintentional ways to use the concept (like "superefficient space engines equals any ship now has the capability to become a planet-wiping RKKV" one), so that I could acknowledge them in the worldbuilding, or patch it up with adding more use limitations to the device.

Comment: Just to make a point, you're asking if a device that violates the laws of physics could have any unintentional side effects.... Can you tell us why you're asking? What specific problem are you trying to solve? Because this looks like a brainstorming fishing-for-ideas question that's discouraged by the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Possibly the laws of thermodynamics are being bent but your device is not described in enough detail to say.  Would suggest investigating Carnot efficiency (e.g. https://www.e-education.psu.edu/egee102/node/1942 ), the theoretical max possible efficiency for a heat engine, and seeing if the remainder of the heat energy the device cannot absorb exceeds what your radiators can handle.

Comment: I want to know if there are any hindsight-obvious unintentional ways to use the concept (like "superefficient space engines equals any ship now has the capability to become a planet-wiping RKKV" one), so that I could acknowledge them in the worldbuilding, or patch it up with adding more use limitations to the device.

Comment: have you made a complicated battery, or an infinite power source? the former shouldn't have problems. the latter allows people to live literally  anywhere.

Comment: It's a battery, definitely not a perpetual machine. Not 100% of the energy is reclamated (Maybe like 95%? IDK), it just unreasonably increases the efficiency.

Comment: E=mc^2 is not about what you think it is, it is not about the limit of energy matter can hold, but how much  energy there is in the just matter existing itself. matter can hold way more energy than E-mc^2

Comment: m = m0/sqrt(1-v^2/c^2) and the energy stored by an electron is enough for BigBang for the speed of electron being in the 1e-{huge-number} close to the speed of light. Not that anything substance (matter or antimatter) can contain such an electron.

Comment: Use a worm-hole that opens towards a lone black hole (nothing around to fall in) and drop your excess heat in there - you'll get to recover nothing, but it won't overheat your ship at any power level your engine will use. Perfect consumerism solution.

Answer (score 4):

**You don't need it to violate the laws of physics!**

Unless lawbreaking is an important part of your story.  Your substance can be [some unusual state of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter).  You will use it as fusion fuel.

E=mc<sup>2</sup>.  Your matter is well suited to be converted to energy.  It is fuel for a fusion reactor.

The ancient tech captures heat energy kicked out by the reactor and regenerates the exotic matter.  Maybe you can add energy to the exotic matter you have and that matter captures the energy as matter.  You will not get back quite as much as you had because presumably you used some of the energy to power your blender and keg cooler.  Entropy takes its tax.

Comment: How about closer to real (yet theoretical) science? Strange matter! A way to contain and use it as energy. Any waste product can be thrown back in and becomes strange matter again.

Comment: The same substance is used to make FTL engines possible, so I thought that killing two birds with one stone would be nicer than inventing some additional pseudoscientific exotic matter for power generation.

Comment: @DarthBiomech - well, you can use negative matter to power your legal Alucbierre drive.  Maybe the same stuff for your friendly fusion engine.,

Comment: The "*breaking the e=mc^2 equation*"  implies that this substance stores a higher energy density than antimatter+matter reacting (21.5 kilotons per gram).  Why bother with carrying a fusion reactor when this stuff is already the ultimate fuel/battery (not to mention the ultimate bomb-making material)?

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan -   Maybe its haunted.  Or smelly.  Or too sexy.  All 3?   I will testify that is a tough combo.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Antimatter wants to go "MEGABOOM" at the slightest hiccup of storage. You must constantly monitor it and the conditions of the containment, or else the warehouse storing some amount of it will wipe out half a continent off the face of the planet. This stuff on the other hand is so inert that you can basically store it in open pools. It needs very specific conditions and some effort to extract that energy though, making it a very poor warhead material.